# How to append the output of subquery to the current main query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a:
**PostTable**:

it has the varchar **Content**, and the INT **groupID**

---

and **JoinedGroupsTable**:

it has the INT **UserID** and the INT **GroupID**

---

Whenever a user joins a group, a record is added to the groupId that has the userid and the groupid.

I want to send the database a query to get all the posts from posttable that has a groupID that the user has joined.

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
Select 
posttable.Content
FROM
posttable, joinedgroupstable
WHERE posttable.GroupID =
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(joinedgroupstable.GroupID SEPARATOR " OR posttable.GroupID =") 
FROM joinedgroupstable 
WHERE joinedgroupstable.UserID=1 )
```

This is just an example code and it doesn't really work yet, because of the last part between the parentheses.

This part:

```
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(joinedgroupstable.GroupID SEPARATOR " OR posttable.GroupID =") 
    FROM joinedgroupstable 
    WHERE joinedgroupstable.UserID=1 )
```

Will output something like "1  OR posttable.GroupID =2 OR posttable.GroupID =3" etc. depending on the groups id that are adjacent to the user in joinedgroupstable, I want to join its output to the main query so it becomes something like this:

```
Select 
posttable.Content
FROM
posttable, joinedgroupstable
WHERE posttable.GroupID =
1  OR posttable.GroupID =2 OR posttable.GroupID =3
```

And so joining the output of the subquery to the main query. I don't know if that is even possible, and would like to know if there a simpler way to do so.

Comment: use the in clause?  `where posttable.groupID in (1,2,3)` or `WHERE posttable.groupID in (SELECT GroupID FROM joinedgroupstable 
WHERE UserID=1)`

Comment: Ah okay, thanks, I think I'll user this syntax instead of several ORs from now on.
Edit: However, my main problem is generating the "1,2,3" from the JoinedGroupsTable (Which are the groupIDs the user '1' has joined) and then adding them as (1,2,3) to the main query

Comment: See my answer as to format to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is what you're after...
I don't see why you need to join to joinedgroupstable so I eliminated it from the join.  Please use inner, left, right join notation instead of the `,` notation in from clause.

This approach can be slow at times and doesn't work at all when the groupID is null in one or both cases (especially in `NOT in` situations)

```
SELECT posttable.Content
FROM posttable
WHERE posttable.GroupID in (SELECT GroupID 
                            FROM joinedgroupstable 
                            WHERE UserID=1 )
```

An alternative way to do this would be to join the tables then limit.  this works well if you need data from both tables.

```
SELECT posttable.Content
FROM posttable
INNER JOIN joinedgroupstable
  on posttable.GroupID = joinedgroupstable.GroupID 
WHERE UserID=1
```

or  using a coorlated query and exists.

This handles nulls well especially when using not in or not exists.

```
SELECT pt.Content
FROM posttable pt
WHERE Exists (SELECT *
              FROM joinedgroupstable jgt
              WHERE UserID=1 
                AND pt.groupID = jgt.groupID)
```

Each has their own strengths and weaknesses in different engines and vary in performance based on data.  you have to test to find which works best for you; but all 3 should produce the same results (except in the null situation)

Comment: Exactly what I needed!!

Edit: Ok I keep pressing enter rather than shift-enter I'll have to get used to it XD


Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's a geat site to ask questions and get answers: just be sure to provide a complete [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and before you ask a question consider [talking to the duck first](https://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/). Yes, I'm serious.

To generate a nice [ascii table](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) data for question or mock up date and problems using http://rextester.com/

Comment: Ah okay then, will read about it, and will take it into consideration when asking a question the next time, thank you!

Comment: It's about making sure we have just the right about of information to help you; not overloading us with stuff not relevant to the question/problem, and often you'll find by breaking a problem down, you end up solving it before posting the question.  It's weird; but it works!